# Lost village of clash of clans

Tags: clash-of-clans

I've used different gmail for supercell than main gmail connected to my CoC village, but unfortunately I forgot my gmail used for supercell. How can I recover my CoC account?

Comment: There is one solution to your problem. Supercell's customer service.

Comment: No it doesn't work. Supercell costumer service just a shit. I've tried too many times through game's help center, email. But it's costumer service is just a bot controlled. It always gives the same respond whatever you ask.

Comment: Well, there is pretty much nothing else we can do there.

Comment: Yeah I think so